Android msal library not populating Device Id
Using the https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android
When checking Entra for the request it is not populating Device ID.
I can not see anywhere to set this option. And I do not want to send customer values and the android id as this will be my apps ID.
People want to confirm the ID and bypass the MFA based on this.

AFAIK The MSAL Android library does not automatically include a "Device ID" in the authentication request. However, you can leverage the DeviceCode or client_info parameters from the response to identify the device. It's important to note that sending custom values like Android ID or app-specific IDs could compromise security and privacy. To bypass MFA based on device, consider using Conditional Access policies in Azure AD instead of relying on custom device IDs

https://pasteboard.co/TgG4KQxDKtCW.png
I have uploaded an image of the data around sign in

To bypass MFA based on device, consider using Conditional Access policies in Azure AD instead of relying on custom device IDs

Sorry, Yes, I am trying to bypass using conditional access. But wanting to use the "Corperate Device" which I was hoping to use the device id. I guess my ask would be, is there any "microsoft id" that is assigned to each device and can be sent, either by default (or setting).
Does it help / change if the device is in shared device mode.

Currently, there is no specific "Microsoft ID" assigned to each device that can be sent by default through MSAL. You might consider using other identifiers that are compliant with your security requirements, but be cautious about sending customer values or Android IDs as they may not meet your needs for security and privacy.

If you want to implement device identification for conditional access policies, you may need to look into using device management solutions like Microsoft Intune, which can provide device compliance and identification features. In shared device mode, the device is treated differently, and you may want to ensure that your application is configured correctly to handle user data securely and appropriately.

Posted the answer please check if helpful:)


Note that: The MSAL Android library doesn't automatically send a "Device ID" when authenticating. However, you can use the DeviceCode or client_info from the authentication response to help identify the device.


Avoid sending custom identifiers like the Android ID or app-specific IDs, as they could pose security and privacy risks.
Instead, to skip MFA based on the device, you can use Conditional Access policies in Azure AD rather than relying on custom device IDs.

To bypass MFA based on device, consider using Conditional Access policies in Azure AD instead of relying on custom device IDs.


There isn't a specific "Microsoft ID" for each device that is automatically sent through MSAL. While you could use other identifiers based on your security requirement.
To implement device identification for conditional access policies, you should consider using device management solutions like Microsoft Intune, which can manage device compliance and provide identification features.
In shared device mode, the device is treated differently, so it's important to ensure that your application is properly configured to securely handle user data and meet privacy requirements.

